# scp unable to resolve hostname on Mac

Tags: macos, ssh

I am on a mac and I have sshed into a remote computer, A. I want to transfer a file from A to my mac.

I tried `scp myfile.txt myusername:`

I got an error:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname {myusername}: Name or service not
>   known.

How do I fix this?

I got my username by typing `id -un`

Answer (score 2):

The right syntax would be.. From remote computer A, you have to run the following command

```
scp myfile.txt yourusername@<ip_addr or hostname of your mac>:/dest/path
```

Or instead from your mac, you can run the below command without logging in the remote machine

```
scp remoteusername@remotecomputerA:/path/to/myfile.txt ./
```